# Column merge using sum in case Oracle APEX

Tags: sql, case, oracle-apex

I need help How can I merge the column into a single column, here is my code, is this method is correct. I want to get the count of the selected row in the table for the columns.[image]

```
SELECT
    CAT_MGR,
    SUM  ( case  when CAT_MGR = 'A' THEN 1    else 0 end ) AS DESIGN,
          sum (case  when CAT_MGR = 'b' THEN 1 else 0  END) AS DESIGN,
          sum (case  when CAT_MGR = 'c' THEN 1 else 0  END) AS DESIGN
 from Table_A
 GROUP BY
  CAT_MGR
```

Can you guys help me I'm a beginner at SQL.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please show us the result that you want, as tabular text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just one row in the resultset, then remove the `group by` clause. Then, if you want to count the three cat mgr together, you can use `in`:

```
select
    sum(case when cat_mgr = 'a' then 1 else 0 end ) as design_a,
    sum(case when cat_mgr = 'b' then 1 else 0 end ) as design_b,
    sum(case when cat_mgr = 'c' then 1 else 0 end ) as design_c,
    sum(case when cat_mgr in ('a', 'b', 'c') then 1 else 0 end ) as design
 from Table_a
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make addion like below in order to get one column "Design"

```sql
SELECT
    CAT_MGR,
      SUM (case  when CAT_MGR = 'A' THEN 1 else 0 end )
    + sum (case  when CAT_MGR = 'b' THEN 1 else 0 END)
    + sum (case  when CAT_MGR = 'c' THEN 1 else 0 END) 
   AS DESIGN
 from TJD_CORE_CATPB_TB
 GROUP BY
  CAT_MGR
```